# What is the best (responsive) way to implement irregular shaped divs/folds?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, clip-path

I've been working on designs with very irregularly-shaped divs, such as rhombuses, trapezoids, etc. I want to know what the most responsive way to deal with these types of designs.

**My current workaround:**
The typical way I implement these designs is by using a combination of clip-path, bloated vertical padding to deal with the clip-path clipping content, and then a negative margin-top on the next fold to cover the white-space created by the clip-path. I declare negative margin-top values with viewport width (ex. -10vw), so the folds adjust based on the width of the browser.

**Problems with current workaround:**
Negative margins usually cause folds to overlap each other, covering the content of other folds. Multiple @media queries needed for it to look acceptable and yet I still encounter certain sizes where the folds overlap each other.

Here's an image to further describe what I mean by irregularly-shaped divs/folds:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZrUK.jpg

Any help would be appreciated. These sort of designs seem to be trending, so your help will serve me and others for future projects as well. Thank you!

Comment: *Negative margins usually cause folds to overlap each other, covering the content of other folds.* --> you also consider padding that will cover you negative margin and you won't have any content overlap

Answer (score 0):

SVGs are a nice way to create section dividers as per your image,(and other complex shapes!) you can target the various shapes inside an svg with css (change fill colour, animations etc), they are widely supported (except for old IE browsers, naturally) and as they are simply vector paths, you can easily stretch, scale and distort, and they're quite small in size.

You might set an svg divider e.g. a wave pattern inside an absolutely positioned div at the bottom of a content section, like below.

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#sect1 {
  background-color: #2baf70;
}

#sect2 {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.row {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 45px 45px 115px 45px;
}

.divider {
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  /* this is an inlined svg taken from a project I'm working on, as an example. as I can't really import a .svg file here */
  width: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 70px;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 70px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  background-repeat-y: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<section id="sect1">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Mock Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, affert omittam urbanitas est te. Eam ne oportere erroribus, quis veri eam cu, usu ex tota verear iudicabit. Vim modus conclusionemque an, verterem explicari sententiae ei duo. Mel cu docendi fierent, sonet dolorum ocurreret
      at vis. Voluptua fabellas electram ut has, tation maluisset voluptatibus sea ex.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
</section>
<section id="sect2">
  <div class="row">
    <h2>Mock Content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, affert omittam urbanitas est te. Eam ne oportere erroribus, quis veri eam cu, usu ex tota verear iudicabit. Vim modus conclusionemque an, verterem explicari sententiae ei duo. Mel cu docendi fierent, sonet dolorum ocurreret
      at vis. Voluptua fabellas electram ut has, tation maluisset voluptatibus sea ex.</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I've seen this sort of implementation in my research. This is great but I'm having difficulty using it in my case. Most of my "dividers" are something like this https://imgur.com/a/D3Y0o3O ,also I'm not very good at making my own svgs. Can I ask how you implemented the transparency in your svg? It seems to have no color but have different levels of opacity.

Comment: Hi Daniel, you can create/edit SVG's in a vector editor program such Adobe Illustrator, if you don't already have it, I'm sure there's free options around, you just need to do a bit of research into whether they can export as and open SVGs. As for transparency, this is automatic, say you created a triangle shape, only the triangle is filled with colour, the surrounding areas are transparent. You can also set partial opacity to a shape's colour fill in the program or with CSS using rgba(). But since you are just starting with SVGs it might be easier for you to do it in the program.

Comment: Also my SVG is using a very pale grey colour. Where you see green on my snippet is actually the transparent part.